# Index Error from Python Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, indexoutofrangeexception

For some reason I keep getting index out of range error for the following code!  All I want to do is compare the next data item to current one to check redundancy.

```
count =  0
for row2 in data2:
    count = count +1
    if data2[count][0]!=row2[0]:
       data3.append(row2)
```

Comment: how many items are in your data2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you should loop in all but the last element of `data2` as follows:

```
for row2 in data2[:-1]:
```

A more compact version for your code is:

```
for i,j in zip(data2[:-1], data2[1:]):
    if i!=j:
       data3.append(i)
```

Even more compact:

```
data3 = [i for i,j in zip(data2[:-1], data2[1:]) if i!=j]
```

Or use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to avoid creating new lists:

```
from itertools import islice, izip

print [i for i, j in izip(islice(data2, None, len(data2) - 2), islice(data2, 1, None)) if i != j]
```

Use `zip` if using python3.

Comment: might as well go all out and use a list comp ;)

Comment: Or use itertools to avoid building more lists `print [i for i,j in izip(islice(data2,None,len(data2)-1),islice(data2, 1,None)) if i != j]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, You should post these as answer so you get credit for them. If not, you are more than welcome to improve my answer. Thanks